# How can you show Chinese characters without installing a language pack?

Tags: html, css, fonts

So our server uses Windows XP and shows Chinese characters like this:

[image]

I can just install the language pack and fix everything but is there a way to just use a css font?

My current code looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ming Imperial';
  src: url('MingImperial.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('MingImperial.woff') format('woff'), url('MingImperial.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('MingImperial.svg#MingImperial') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family: 'Ming Imperial' !important; }
```

So `Ming Imperial` is a Chinese font but I still see boxes for Chinese characters though English characters are turned into Chinese.

Is there a proper way to do this without installing the language packs?

Comment: Have you specified ISO language code

Comment: Thank you @Duck_dragon, specifying the correct ISO lang did the trick.

Comment: sidenote: if your servers run Windows XP, your servers are probably already compromised and it's worth upgrading to an operating system that is still supported and receiving security updates. That's not what you want to hear, but it still bears mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:lang()` pseudo-class selector and specify ISO language code. Then write your css like this:

```
:lang(zh-Hans)  {
font-family: DFKai-SB,BiauKai,serif;
}
```

The HTML Fragment:

```
<ul>
<li lang="zh-Hans">欢迎</li>
<li lang="zh-Hant">歡迎</li>
</ul>
```

For more information you can always go to the offical site
[Qa-CSS-Lang](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang)

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` tag, preferably before anything else, even the `<title>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So adding `lang="zh-Hant"` did the trick. Thanks to @Duck_dragon.